# How can I avoid circular dependency in my Makefile compiling obj file with g++ and gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, g++

I tried to create a makefile for a project that use c++ and c.
I need to compile those file in order to make de .o file, but when I compile using make I have circular dependency that is dropped.

I don't know why this error occurs as I tried to separate the building of .o files that comes from .c and .o files that comes froms .cpp files.

Here is my makefile :

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
SRC++ = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRC++:.cpp=.o) $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP = $(SRC:.c=.d) $(SRC++:.cpp=.d)

CC=gcc
CXX=g++

CFLAGS = -Wall
CXXFLAGS = -Wall

all: $(OBJ)

%.c : %.o
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@  

%.cpp : %.o
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@  

# Clean the project
clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJ) $(DEP)

-include $(DEP)
```

Do you have any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Where is the command to link all the $(OBJ) into a binary?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I don't need it for the moment, it is just for generate .o files

Comment: The answer below is correct.  But for future reference when asking for help please always include (via cut and paste) the exact command line you invoked and the exact error message output you received.  In this case, make will print the names of the rules that were circular and knowing that would have made it even easier for readers to know what the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules you wrote are `%.cpp : %.o`  and `%.c : %.o`.  You wrote those rules the wrong way around.  The target being built must be to the left of the colon, and the things it depends on must be to the right.

The error message tells you about a circular dependency because GNU Make defines an implicit rule where the dependencies are defined in the correct direction.

Comment: Thank, you I just modified but now I have two targets ".o" but the make only calls the first one and I need to calls the two. Is it specific for compiling combined cpp and c ?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  If you have a `.cpp` file then Make should use the corresponding rule to build a `.o` file from it.  If you have a `.c` file it should use the corresponding rule to build a `.o` file from it.  If you have `foo.cpp` and also `foo.c` (two files with the same base name) that would be a bad idea: rename one of them.  If you continue having trouble I need to see a directory listing, your Makefile, and the full output from `make`.

Comment: Anyway, since your question is about how to avoid a circular dependency and we already fixed that, I think you should mark my answer as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark.  Then you can ask a new question about your new problem, but be sure to include the pieces of information I asked for above.